# Free image for the "grab" cursor for IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11, w3c

I am looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697067/css-for-grabbing-cursors-drag-drop/35517611) and its answers, and it seems the only legitimate way to implement a grab cursor in IE11 is to use an image like this:

```
 cursor: url(images/grab.cur);
```

Browsing the internet I don't find any such images for which I can be 100% sure that they are free to use without any obligations.

Does anyone know an image for "grab" cursor that is definitely free and without any obligations?

Answer (score 1):

**You can also have the cursor be an image:**

```
.custom {
  cursor: url(images/my-cursor.png), auto;
}
```

**Or you can use some WebKit only cursors:**

```
-webkit-zoom-in
-webkit-zoom-out
-webkit-zoom-grab
-webkit-zoom-grabbing
```

or you can download the cursors used by Gmail. Download http://ssl.gstatic.com/ui/v1/icons/mail/images/2/openhand.cur and save it as "grab.cur" and http://ssl.gstatic.com/ui/v1/icons/mail/images/2/closedhand.cur and save it as "grabbing.cur" in the same folder as your HTML document. Then insert the following codes in you HTML document according to if you want the grab cursor or the grabbing cursor:

```
Grab cursor: style="cursor: url(grab.cur), move"
Grabbing cursor: style="cursor: url(grabbing.cur), move"
```

You're good to go!

Comment: That's what I'm saying - the only way to have this cursor in IE11 is to use an image. The question is where to get this kind of image that is free and without any obligations.

Comment: you can download the cursors used by Gmail. Download http://ssl.gstatic.com/ui/v1/icons/mail/images/2/openhand.cur and save it as "grab.cur" and http://ssl.gstatic.com/ui/v1/icons/mail/images/2/closedhand.cur and save it as "grabbing.cur" in the same folder as your HTML document. Then insert the following codes in you HTML document according to if you want the grab cursor or the grabbing cursor:

Grab cursor: style="cursor: url(grab.cur), move"
Grabbing cursor: style="cursor: url(grabbing.cur), move"

Comment: Ok, but what indicates that they are free to use?

Comment: what do you mean when you say free to use. Ofcourse they are free to use.

Comment: That they don't need a licence for commercial use.

Comment: So actually your question is about copyrights on image assets. Perhaps it's better suited to https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/. In any case, if the cursor is super generic, I don't think anyone will notice or care. There is also this, an excellent resource: https://thenounproject.com/search/?q=cursor

Comment: @MarsAndBack Thank you for the suggestion. The noun project icons don't seem to be free though.

Comment: Well, nothing is stopping you from making your own. When you're done, it may look exactly like 1000's of other cursors. There's only so much you can do with 16x16 and black. Or just keep searching the internet.

Answer (score 1):

If you want any obligation free cursor file, better create your own Image,

That is the best way to be sure, I have created few Images like that in past.

Create a PNG file and use any online converter to convert that file to CUR file.

Hope this solves what you are looking for..