# Change cursor from grab to grabbing while mouse is clicked down?

Tags: html, css

I have an element that can be moved/dragged and want the cursor to be set to `grab` while hovering over it and changed to `grabbing` when users click and hold the mouse down.

My current setup is almost identical to what is suggested in the most up-voted solution to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697067/css-for-grabbing-cursors-drag-drop). The problem is that the cursor doesn't change to `grabbing` until the user releases the mouse click (which was described in the comments of the linked posted, but no solution). Is there a way to change the state of the cursor when it is initially clicked until it is released?

[Minimum reproducible example link](https://codesandbox.io/s/young-pond-9kcgc?file=/index.html)

```css
.outer-box {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  cursor: grab;
}
.outer-box:active {
  cursor: grabbing;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-box"></div>
```

Comment: I'm using Chrome: when I click on the element the cursor does change to grabbing.

Comment: @Terry right when you click, or after you've let go?

Comment: I've tried both FF and Chrome on my Mac, and get the grabbing state when the mouse is pressed down. I don't have to wait for release.

Comment: @beltouch I moved my browser from my external monitor to my main screen and it worked! Must have something to do with the display.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use the `onmouseover`, `onmousedown`, `onmouseup`, `onmouseleave` attributes, and connect them each to a function that changes to the specific type of cursor you need for each of these events

e.g.

```
function() {
  document.getElementByClass("outer-box").style.cursor = "pointer";
}
```