# Grabbing cursor is lost as soon as mouse start moving

Tags: css

I am trying to use grab & grabbing cursors. Not sure why as soon as I **start dragging** the `li` cursor changes to pointer+ as you can see from the image. I want it to use grabbing cursor. What have I done wrong?

[image]

I am following [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697067/css-for-grabbing-cursors-drag-drop) and tried all the solutions with most up votes. I thought this is very straight forward. Here is my setup:

```
<li class="draggable" draggable="true">
    <h2 class="title"></h2>
    <h3 class="emoji"></h3>
    <div class="del"></div>
    <p class="desc"></p>
</li>
```

```
.draggable {
  cursor: move;
  cursor: grab;
  cursor: -moz-grab;
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
}
.draggable:active {
  cursor: grabbing;
  cursor: -moz-grabbing;
  cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
}
```

Comment: Mmhm the [answer further below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35517611/10441671) informs that vendor-specific styles should be first and the standard last. The browser will apply the last one found. So you may be experiencing browser kinks..?

Comment: Looks like it should work. What browser are you using?

Comment: I tried chrome and edge.