# How to remove the plus icon when grabbing on a drop and drag element

Tags: javascript, css, cursor, draggable

I am trying to remove the plus icon on a grabbing cursor on `dragenter`.

[image]

I tried:

```js
  function dragStart(e) {
    e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'none';
  }

  function dragEnter(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'none';
  }
```

which actually removes the icon but that would not allow me to drop the element.

[image]

Is there a way to remove the icon without restricting the element from being dropped?

Comment: i don't think is easly done, since there a few browser that don't support this.

Comment: does it answer your question?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18294634/5347939

Comment: @zhisme, I already tried that one but it seems that it doesn't override the cursor when dragging.

Comment: for anyone wondering how I solved the issue, I haven't. Instead of removing it, I replaced it with `e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move'` on `dragStart` which shows a move icon which is more logical than showing the plus icon.