# Make the cursor look like HTML5 drag and drop cursor

Tags: html, css, drag-and-drop, mouse-cursor

Drag and drop in HTML5 uses the following cursor shape when an element is dragged over the drop zone:

[image]

Would it be possible to set cursor to above shape without using drag and drop?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS for grabbing cursors (drag & drop)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697067/css-for-grabbing-cursors-drag-drop)

Comment: Thanks for the response, the grabbing cursor shape isn't the same as the one above.

Comment: it is not, but the mechanism for assigning a cursor _shape_ on `hover` is the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to MDN:

> By default, the browser supplies an image that appears beside the pointer during a drag operation. However, an application may define a custom image with the setDragImage() method, as shown in the following example.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API#define_the_drag_image

So in theory, you can do the same:

1. Use the User-Agent to determine what's the most likely cursor design the user has (e.g. Chrome/Edge; Windows/Mac, etc)
2. Provide the appropriate cursor as an image, e.g.: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaRox.png

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  cursor: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaRox.png"), default;
}
```

... but obviously this isn't a very optimal approach. Unless it's urgent, wait for the cursor to hopefully be added natively.