# CSS cursor URL not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, url, cursor

I am trying to use a custom cursor with the URL given in the answer to this question: (the grab cursor that gmail uses)

[How can you implement a grabbing cursor icon in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632532/how-can-you-implement-a-grabbing-cursor-icon-in-chrome)

I am using this exact method shown in the snippet, which works. But when I try it with my actual project I get this error in the javascript console:

*GET file://ssl.gstatic.com/ui/v1/icons/mail/images/2/openhand.cur net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND*

What what does this error mean? What can I do to make it work?

Code:

```js
$('.hover').addClass('grab');
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 200px;
  width: 50%;
}

.grab {
  cursor: url(//ssl.gstatic.com/ui/v1/icons/mail/images/2/openhand.cur), default; !important
}
```

```html
<div class="hover">

</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why not just save the cursor locally and change the path instead of using a google hosted one? Here's the file http://ssl.gstatic.com/ui/v1/icons/mail/images/2/openhand.cur

Comment: your url starts with `//` - that means use the "protocol" of the page - if you are loading the page locally using `file:///` - then of course `file://...` wont exist ... this is not a chrome specific problem, all browsers WILL fail

Answer (score 0):

`file://ssl.gstatic.com/ui/v1/icons/mail/images/2/openhand.cur`
You accidentally said `file`;  it is supposed to be `https://ssl.gstatic.com/`. It requires the `https://` for it to **work**.